# Problems with ResolutionPath using SQLProvider with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, f#, type-providers

Trying to use F# SQLProvider with SQLite, I keep getting the error message `The type provider 'FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlTypeProvider' reported an error: Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found.`

Code:

```
open FSharp.Data.Sql

let [<Literal>] resolutionPath1 = 
    __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + @"..\..\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.102.0\build\net46\x86\" 
let [<Literal>] resolutionPath2 =
    @"f:\proj\WanLog\packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.102.0\build\net46\x86"

let [<Literal>] connectionString = 
    "Data Source=" + @"F:\proj\WanLog\WanLog\bin\Debug\WanIPLog.s3db"

type sql = SqlDataProvider< 
              ConnectionString = connectionString,
              DatabaseVendor = Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.SQLITE,
              ResolutionPath = resolutionPath2,
              IndividualsAmount = 1000,
              UseOptionTypes = true >
```

I've tried both relative and absolute paths (resolutionPath1 and resolutionPath2) and verified that SQLite.Interop.dll is in fact present in the directory referenced in resolutionPath2.

The target framework and CPU, .NET 4.6 and x86, are AFAIK in sync with the specified directory (ending with \net46\x86). What have I missed?

#### Update:

I've updated the [SQLProvider SQLite documentation](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/sqlite.html) according to the answer to this question.

#### Update 2:

System.Data.SQLite solved this problem in version 1.0.104.0. See [this discussion](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/d4728aecb76adffb227e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your resolution path to the following, and this should have both `SQLiteInterop.dll` and `System.Data.SQLite.dll`, copy the file if it's not there:

> packages\System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.102.0\lib\net46

Check with `File.Exists` if necessary. Are you sure the x86 version is correct by the way. I would build for x64 and copy the x64 dll there. Btw, I would also reference and `open System.Data.SQLite`.

Comment: Usually Visual Studio runs on x86 mode even if it says it's x64. So try using the x86 version of the dll.

Comment: @TuomasHietanen I'm not sure I follow. Sqlite is actually finicky regarding bitness. And while VS is indeed a 32bit application on most modern platforms it's better to target 64bit. Obviously if you are using FSI you need to set it to 64bit as well. Why wouldn't you take advantage of the larger address space especially for a db.

Comment: I experimented a little with this, and apparently it also works if `ResolutionPath` points to a directory that contains `System.Data.SQLite.dll` and has `x64` and `x86` subdirectories with `SQLiteInterop.dll`, allowing you to select the "Any CPU" target.

Comment: I've created a pull request to update the [SQLProvider SQLite documentation](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/sqlite.html), to include all this info. Thanks to the SQLProvider maintainer who merged it and rebuilt the doc page, all on a Sunday morning. :)

Comment: A follow-up on this: copying the x64 and x86 native subdirectories will soon be unnecessary. Joe Mistachkin is modifying the System.Data.SQLite NuGet package especially for us F# users. The update will probably make the next release, ver 1.0.104.0.